# How to model a HTML table with two cells per column in React?

Tags: reactjs

I've been learning React recently, and I'm running into a problem trying to model and render a HTML table of the following structure (note the columns which are split into two using the colspan attribute for the headers).

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----+-------------------+
|     Col 1 Header    |     Col 2 Header    | ... | Col N header      |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+---------+---------+
| Data 1A  | Data 1B  | Data 2A  | Data 2B  | ... | Data NA | Data NB |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+---------+---------+
| Data 1A  | Data 1B  | Data 2A  | Data 2B  | ... | Data NA | Data NB |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+---------+---------+
```

I've modelled the table like this:

Main component `Table`, which renders:

```
<table> 
  <thead>
    <tr>
    {headers}  <!-- <Header/> components -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {rows}     <!-- <Row/> components -->
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

The `Header` components render as `<th colSpan="2">Col 1 Header</th>`

Each `Row` renders as

```
<tr>
  {cells}    <!-- <Cell/> components -->
</tr>
```

Now the `Cell` component is where I run into trouble as I want to split each column into two sub columns (as the header columns have `colSpan="2"`.)

Since [ReactComponent's render()](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render) method has to return a single child component, I can't figure out how to return the two cells like this: `<td>Data 1A</td><td>Data 1B</td>`

In non-table situations I could return something like

```
<div>
   <div class="subcol1">Data 1A</div>
   <div class="subcol2">Data 1B</div>
</div>
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to achive this with a table. Maybe the way I've designed the component structure is a bit off?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right now it's impossible to make a component in React that renders as two table cells. In the future it may be possible but for now, your best bet is probably to make a plain JS function that returns the cells:

```
function cellsForData(data) {
    return [
        <td>Data 1A</td>,
        <td>Data 1B</td>
    ];
}
```

You can include this in your `cells` array for your table component and everything should work.

Answer (score 39):

in react it should be  `colSpan` attribute not `colspan`.

```
<td colSpan={2}>

</td>
```

more info [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/185)